# unable to solve rspec issue for a remote file resource

Tags: ruby, tdd, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chefspec

I tried to write rspec for one of my remote_file resource. But I am unsuccessful to make it.
My concept is using remote_file it should download a remote file which is a zip file. What happen is rspec is expecting more after It downloaded remotely.

This is my resource declaration:

```
remote_file zip_file_location do
  source http://google.com
  mode '0754'
  action :create
end​
```

This is my rspec test:

```
it 'creates a remote_file ' do
    expect(chef_run).to create_remote_file(::File.join(Chef::Config[:file_cache_path], 'sonarqube-5.6.6.zip'))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your resource

```
remote_file 'sonarqube-5.6.6.zip' do
 source 'http://google.com/'
 action :create
 mode 00755
end
```

and this is rspec for your resource

```
it 'creates a remote_file ' do
  expect(chef_run).to create_remote_file('sonarqube-5.6.6.zip').with(
      source: "http://google.com",
      mode: 00755
  )
end
```

If you want to have configuration value from attributes/default.rb for location of your saved file you must mock this in your rspec file:

```
describe 'lecturio_ds::webfrontend' do
  context 'When all attributes are default, on an unspecified platform'  do
  let(:chef_run) do
    ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new do |node|
      node.set['file_cache_path'] = '/tmp'
    end.converge(described_recipe)
  end
# place for your spec
end
```

and after that you can verify it `create_remote_file('/tmp/sonarqube-5.6.6.zip')`.

I don't understand why you use in your rspec file `File.join` there.

Comment: @gig I gave the path of the remote file where it needs to be installed

Comment: Rspec is like unit testing for your code, there is no real file ended in your desire directory.

Answer (score 0):

For few reasons this worked me, I modified my code by giving path for remote file which helped me to solve rspec to expect exactly the zip file location

this helped me to solve rspec

```html
remote_file 'Download zip file'do
Path zip_file_location   
source http://google.com
mode '0754'
action :create
end​


it 'creates a remote_file ' do
expect(chef_run).to create_remote_file('Download remote file')
end
```